# WTForm "OR" conditional validator? (Either email or phone)

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

```
class ContactForm(Form):
  name = StringField('Name',
                     validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=255)])
  email = StringField('Email',
                      validators=[Optional(), Email(), Length(max=255)])
  phone = StringField('Phone number',
                      validators=[Optional(), NumberRange(min=8, max=14)])
  comment = TextAreaField(u'Comment',
                          validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Is there anyway to specify a validator such that either `email` or `phone` is required?

Comment: can create a custom `validate()` method and check that one is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `validate` method on the form and do some manual checking. Something like this might get you started.

```
class MyForm(Form):
    name = StringField('Name',
                 validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=255)])
    email = StringField('Email',
                      validators=[Optional(), Email(), Length(max=255)])
    phone = StringField('Phone number',
                      validators=[Optional(), NumberRange(min=8, max=14)])
    comment = TextAreaField(u'Comment',
                          validators=[DataRequired()])
    def validate(self):
        valid = True
        if not Form.validate(self):
            valid = False
        if not self.email and not self.phone:
            self.email.errors.append("Email or phone required")
            valid = False
        else:
            return valid
```

Comment: That works. I notice that when the other fields fail, the second if clause will not be triggered. Is there a way to trigger the check on self.email.data or self.phone.data during Form.validate?

Comment: Edited it a bit, see if that works. If so, please accept the answer so future readers can benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you @reptilicus. I had minor changes to the answer for it to work.

1. Had to check for data field `self.email.data and self.phone.data`
2. Also had to return valid at the end of the `validate()` method instead of `else` condition.

> ```
> def validate(self):
>     valid = True
>     if not Form.validate(self):
>         valid = False
>     if not self.email and not self.phone:
>         self.email.errors.append("Email or phone required")
>         valid = False
>     return valid
> ```