# Flask-WTF OR validation

Tags: python, validation, flask, flask-wtforms

I am trying to make a email contact form with 0.14 Flask-wtf.
I would like to include a "either one" validation in my from, which user have to enter aleast email or phone number when submit. 
This post here : [WTForm "OR" conditional validator? (Either email or phone)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38486527/wtform-or-conditional-validator-either-email-or-phone) is exactly what I am looking for however, it does not work apart from the default InputReuired validation.
Is there a way to implement this type of validation? Thanks.

app.py

```
@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():

form = ContactForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate_on_submit() == False:
        message = 'All fields are required.'
        flash(message)
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:
        return 'Form posted.'

elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

Forms.py

```
class ContactForm(FlaskForm):
  name = StringField('Name',
                      validators=[InputRequired(message='Please enter your name.')])
  email = StringField('Your Email', 
                       validators=[Optional(), Email(message='Please check the format of your email.')])
  phone = StringField('Your Phone Number', validators=[Optional()])
  word = TextAreaField('Your messages', 
                        validators=[InputRequired(message='Please say something.')])
  submit = SubmitField('Send')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be easier to do this not within the Forms.py but rather the app.py.

For example,

```
def is_valid(phone):
    try: 
        int(phone)
        return True if len(phone) > 10 else False
    except ValueError:
        return False

@app.route('/contact', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact():

form = ContactForm()

if request.method == 'POST':
    if form.validate_on_submit() == False:
        message = 'All fields are required.'
        flash(message)
        return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
    else:
        if not (form.email.data or form.phone.data):
            form.email.errors.append("Email or phone required")
            return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
        else if not is_valid(form.phone.data):
            form.phone.errors.append("Invalid Phone number")
            return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
        return 'Form posted.'

elif request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('contact.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Hi. I tired your method and it seems no working. When I submit nothing in any field the form validate itself and flash name/message error. But when I fill in the name and message, leave email/phone empty, the form was posted.

Comment: @GreenKoala Looks like the problem is I didn't reference the actual value using .data - try that.

Comment: On the if statement, I still had self.phone.data from the previous example. It should be adapted now.

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks for the solution. Would you mind to explain a bit more on how to use .data?

Comment: Yeah no problem. So each form field is an object and it has attributes errors, data, and probably some others that I don't know about. So if you want to actually see the value of it, you have to do form.emails.data rather than just form.emails, which is what we were doing earlier.

Comment: So when you actually post the form, and want to do something with the actual values, like store them in a database or something, use form.email.data and form.phone.data to get the actual values they typed in

Comment: Also, would you mind accepting the answer when you get a chance? Thanks :)

Comment: So it act like a detector to check if user typed in something? Can I also check wording with it? Forexample, someone type'fxxk' and I dont want to accept that.

Comment: Yeah, you can leverage python to do anything. On the email, it looks like you already made sure it's of the proper format. For the phone I would do a check to make sure it's at least a proper length: if len(form.phone.data) < 10 or something like that. I would also make sure there aren't any letters in it. using something like all([x.isdigit() for x in form.phone.data.split("-")])

Comment: Phone does not raise any error message how do I do that when I add such rule?

Comment: @GreenKoala See the updated version. I've added a function to make sure it's all digits or can be turned into all digits.

Comment: I've added a function to make sure it's all digits or can be turned into all digits. You might need to edit it to allow dashes and parenthesis, but you get the idea. You should be able to improve that function using other examples on here.

Comment: It worked!! But it does not show error message while int(phone)==False> Opps. I need to also update the templates!